# API PagSeguro como pegar status de pagamento por ID

Tags: php, api

Olá, procurei bastante sobre isso olhando a git do PagSeguro mais não consegui entender, oque eu quero é o seguinte

meusite.com/check.php?id=ID-DA-TRANSAÇÂO-?token=MEU-TOKEN?email=MEU-EMAIL

Tipo se existir o pagamento com id da transação colocado no link para a conta e token ele vai retornar todas as informações (echo $info dar_dump?) do pagamento, não entendi a API do PagSeguro o suficiente para fazer isso então vim pedir a ajuda de vocês, obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente vc vai fazer isso:

```
$curl=curl_init("https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v3/transactions/{{codigo-transacao}}?{{credenciais}}");
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$xml=simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($curl));
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($xml);
```

- codigo-transacao = como já sugere é esse id que vc disse, mas apenas o id, sem o `id=`
- credenciais = as credenciais cadastradas `email=SEU_EMAIL&token=SEU_TOKEN`
- exemplo da url completa: `https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v3/transactions/9E884542-81B3-4419-9A75-BCC6FB495EF1?email=seu_email@dominio.com&token=seu_token`

  Você busca todas as informações da transação.